# Sennheiser MKH70 temperature range

Tags: microphone, field-recording, sennheiser

I can't find any information from Sennheiser about temperature range (specs [here](http://da-dk.sennheiser.com/global-downloads/file/2838/MKH70_ProductSheet.pdf)).

What is the Sennheiser MKH70 temperature range?

For example, is it possible to use in -15 C?

Comment: Whoever voted this off-topic should click the specs link. The mic in question is a professional shotgun mic, not consumer audio equipment.